# Codeigniter on Nginx, url segments

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I've been developing a website with Codeigniter on my local machine, running an Apache server. I did not realise the production server would be running Nginx. When attempting to run CI, I now run into the problem that those pretty URLs with segments in them do not work. I keep getting a 404 page.

I have no experience with Nginx, but I found a few code snippits via Google that I tried.

I'm in a shared hosting situation, meaning I have limited configuration options. This results in the configuration interface rejecting most of the configuration snippits I've copy-pasted into it in an attempt to get it to work.

So far, I've found out it rejects the keywords `server_name`, `root` and `include`, which seem to appear in every single solution I've found.

As I have little knowledge on the subject, I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do (i.e. get Codeigniter up and running with slash-separated URL parts rather than a query string) is even possible when I'm not able to use the afformentioned keywords.

Is there a 'default' piece of Nginx configuration available for Codeigniter that might help me out here? Or is my situation too limited to even allow for a solution? Should I just ask my host for help?

EDIT: Note that I'm not trying to remove index.php from my URLs to make them more appealing - I'm not at that point yet. This is about URL segments in general - you know, the default behaviour of Codeigniter.

Comment: "Hiding index.php" and "url segments in general" - is really the same task - need to enable rewriting option.

Comment: I disagree. On http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html, it says that by default it does include index.php, and provides a rewrite to fix this. The URI segments are a default functionality without rewrites. That appear to be two different scenario's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you say "Slash-separated URLs", you must understand, that it's just some URL, that is leads to non-existing file (for example, site.com/controller/action/param1/value1 leads to "folders" /controller/action/param1 and "file" value1), and tghis situation is solved by using mod_rewrite in apache - it just rewrites any URL, that points to non-existing file to a url, pointing to index.php. So, In nginx you need just the same.

In your nginx configuration you have to add this locations:

```
# for rewriting non-existing url-s to index.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

and

```
#location, that enables to process *.php files thorugh php-fpm (fastcgi)
#it's possible that you already have this block configured, and don't need to change it.
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;        
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
    fastcgi_index index.php;        include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
}
```

Also, If it doesn't help, just google "Configure nginx for codeigniter", or, ask your webhoster support "please, make changes to config so url rewriting could start to work"

Comment: That's exactly the config I've been finding all evening, but the input field my host provides doesn't allow the `include` statement on line 6 of your second snippit. I'll be asking them why, I guess.

Comment: You have to ask your hosting' technical support for it. It's a very simple and widely used config, so, if your hosting doesn't give you ability to set it manually, they should do it by hands.